# Dns.GetHostAddresses() giving same IP Address for different host name in the same domain

Tags: c#

I am trying to get IP Addresses of the different computers which are in the same domain by providing HostName to the Dns.GetHostAddresses() member functon but it returns 69.172.200.109 IP Address for all the computers. I failed to know the exact solution for this. Solution for this is much appreciated.

IPAddress[] ips;
                ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
                foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        ipAddress = ip.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

Comment: Kindly post your code

Comment: If you call this from a web application, you'll get the server's IP, not that of the client.

Answer (score -1):

The scenario you are encountering is very much possible if there is another server in between, that routes the requests to appropriate server based on host name received in request. The address you are being served might be the address of that intermediate server. Please see [Virtual web hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) for more details.

Secondly, if it's a local DNS that you are querying, make sure you double check the addresses configured there.

Answer (score -1):

you can try bellow code to get all ip address your domain

```
  String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();

// Find host by name
IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);

// Enumerate IP addresses
foreach(IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah! for local computer it's working fine, but i am trying to get another computer address by providing that computer name. Both computers are in same domain, I found problem here, Still it is returning 69.172.200.109

Comment: above code will only work if your computers are in same intranet !